# Сравнение в PHP switch

Tags: php, вконтакте, api

работаю с API вконтакте.Сделал небольшой скрипт, где идет сравнение по Switch , сообщения пользователя, с моими данными, вот пример:

```html
switch ($message) {
    case "купить":
        $text = $buy;
        break;
    case "киви":
        $text = $qiwi;
    case "карта":
        $text = $card;
        break;
    default:
       $text = $error;
}
```

т.е , если $message == например карта, то переменной $text присваевается значение $card, но на самом деле, когда выполняется этот код, переменной $text присваевается постоянно значение переменной $error , почему так? В чем проблема?

Comment: наверное в том что у вас $message не соответствует не одному из условий switch

Comment: ну это как бы логично. Вопрос только в том, почему оно не соответствует... Если я отправляю слово "купить", а оно мне все равно $error возвращает

Comment: Кодировка совпадает скрипта с получаемым текстом?

Comment: у меня ваше выражение работает, выведите перед switch ($message) var_dump($message) и покажите результат, и у вас после case "киви" нет оператора break;

Comment: Rootware, спасибо) Точно, кодировка не совпадала)